# How to connect with coreNLP server with username password?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I have created coreNLP server in Google App Engine and I have provided username and password over there  using following properties: -port **** -username **user** -password **pass**.

And from Python, I have come to know to pass username and password in properties.

First I am creating NLP object using following function and passing URL:

```
sNLP = StanfordCoreNLP(serverurl)
```

Then I am calling annotate with data and property , and my username and password is there in props.

```
props: {
    "annotators": "pos,sentiment",
    "pipelineLanguage": "en",
    "outputFormat": "json",
    "username": "**user**",
    "password": "***pass***",
    "maxCharLength": -1
}

sNLP.annotate(data, props)
```

before providing authentication it was working fine, but after that I am not getting any response from server.

So should I pass username and password while creating sNLP object? If yes then how? I haven't found any documentation related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for this will soon be in the next release of our Python code which should be very soon, though it is not in the current version.

`pip install stanfordnlp`

Repo is here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp

If you clone that and checkout `dev` and run `pip install -e .` you can get the latest `dev` branch code.

Example:

```
from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient

with CoreNLPClient(annotators="tokenize,ssplit,pos", memory="4G", server_id='my_server_id', username='user-1234', password='1234') as client:
    ann = client.annotate('Hello World!', output_format='text', username='user-1234', password='1234')
    print(ann)
```

If you want to attempt other solutions, note that this code is setting `auth` to a `requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)` when making a POST request with the `requests` library.